# Git rebase empty branch

Tags: git, branch, rebase

Lets say I have taken a branch of `main`, called `BR1`.

I commit 3 changes to `BR1` (c1, c2, c3).

I then take a branch of `BR1`, called `BR2`.

`main` ------> `BR1` (c1) (c2) (c3) -----> `BR2`

I have now decided that I actually didn't want to branch `BR2` from `BR1`, but instead I want `BR2` to be branched from `main` ... i.e I don't want c1, c2, c3 on `BR2`

```
`main` ------> `BR1` (c1) (c2) (c3) 
       ------> `BR2`
```

Am I right in thinking I just need to rebase `BR2` onto `main`?

```
git switch main
git pull
git switch BR2
git rebase -i main
git push -f
```

I tested this and it worked, but I was a little worried as the interactive rebase had

```
pick c1
pick c2
pick c3
```

which I had to change to

```
drop c1
drop c2
drop c3
```

So wasn't sure if something was going to break.

The other confusing thing for me was that `BR2` has no commits on it, i.e when I made the `BR2` branch, I made no commits to it, so I wasn't even sure if its valid to rebase an 'empty' branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `BR2` really has no commits of its own, you may simply do a hard reset to the `main` branch:

```
# from BR2
git reset --hard main
```

If `BR2` did have its own commits, then you could use a rebase onto:

```
# from BR2, again
git rebase --onto main c3
```

Comment: thankyou - I knew I was overcomplicating it in the first case ....